# How to add values to a named list only if the name is present?

Tags: r, list, named

I have the following example named list:

```
> named_list <- c(0,0,0)
> names(named_list) <- c('a','b','c')
> named_list
a b c 
0 0 0
```

And I have a vector with values that I want to have changed

```
> set_to_1 <- c('b','c','d')
```

So now I change the values

```
> named_list[set_to_1] <- 1
```

And I get

```
> named_list
a b c d 
0 1 1 1
```

However, I would like to get

```
> named_list
a b c
0 1 1
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this should work for you:

```
named_list[names(named_list) %in% set_to_1] <- 1
named_list
# a b c 
# 0 1 1
```

Or this:

```
named_list[intersect(names(named_list), set_to_1)] <- 1
```